# Case Study: Speed up Mapply in R

Tags: r, performance, mapply

I had to do a program which finds "similar" sentences.
In this context, sentences are just integer vectors. (we can assume we have pre-processed here strings and word sentences into integer vectors). For the sake of simplicity we have all sentences with the same length, and two sentences are similar if they differ just by only *ONE* word replaced by another

for example (4,3,1,2) and (4,2,1,2) are similar, as they differ only with the second number 3 being replaced by 2.

the sentences are stored in a data.table `DT`. with 2 columns, 1 being the ID, the other being a char vector.

we are given a list of pair IDs in `ID_pair`, and we need to check if the corresponding sentences in `DT` are similar.

Here is an example of the code.
Now, I am NOT satisfied with the implementation with `mapply`, as i find it too slow. (10 seconds for only 100,000 pair checks !!)
I am sure this can be done much much more efficiently. [and i need to as i've got to scan for tens or hundreds of millions of checks for that project !]

notes:
(1) i've tried to implement a hash_table. it doesn't make things faster, strangely.
(2) maybe this has to do that the column V of `DT` is a list and that causes problem ? what alternative do I have ?
(3) if there is a solution to do faster, i need in a second part, to look for another notion of similarity where 2 sentences differ by just adding (anywhere) *one* word. so thats why i chose a list in this example to store the data, to be able to put in the same column sentences of different lengths.
maybe this is wrong ?

thanks

```
library(hash)
library(data.table)

is_pair_sub <- function(ID1,ID2){
        sum(!DT$V[[which(DT$ID==ID1)]]==DT$V[[which(DT$ID==ID2)]])==1
        # sum(!values(s_hash,ID1)[,1]==values(s_hash,ID2)[,1])==1
}

set.seed(123)

N <- 2000
k <- 4 #size of alphabet

V <- lapply(1:N,function(x){sample(1:k,4,replace=TRUE)})
DT <- data.table(ID=sample(1:N),V)

N_pair_sub <- 100000
ID_pair <- data.table(matrix(sample(1:N,2*N_pair_sub,replace=TRUE),nrow=N_pair_sub,ncol=2))

s_hash <- hash(DT$ID,DT$V)

print(system.time({
x <- mapply(is_pair_sub,ID_pair$V1,ID_pair$V2) }))

ID_pair[x]
```

**EDIT**

thanks to @Khashaa for his answer below.
This works well because of the simple vectorized form of the first kind of similarity.

what about the problem of comparing if 2 sentences differ just by 1 insertion

```
is_pair_edit1 <- function(ID1, ID2) { #ID1 and #ID2 should be 1 length apart}

        split1=values(s_hash,ID1)[,1]
        split2=values(s_hash,ID2)[,1]
        l2=length(split2)

        l1=l2-1 #this is by construction


        #         if (! (len1==len2)){return(FALSE) }
        #         this has been already tested

        index = 1
        diff = 0
        if (l1==l2) {return(FALSE)}
        if (l1>l2) {

                while ( index < l1) {
                        if( diff==0) {
                                if (split1[index] != split2[index]) {diff=1}
                                else {index <- index + 1}
                        }
                        else { #diff==1
                                if (split1[index+1]!=split2[index]) {return(FALSE)}
                                else {index <- index + 1}
                        }
                } #end of while
                return (TRUE) #should be TRUE anyway if we get there 
        } #end of if

        else {

                while ( index < l2) {
                        if( diff==0) {
                                if (split1[index] != split2[index]) {diff=1}
                                else {index <- index + 1}
                        }
                        else { #diff==1
                                if (split2[index+1]!=split1[index]) {return(FALSE)}
                                else {index <- index + 1}
                        }
                } #end of while
                return (TRUE) #should be TRUE anyway if we get there 
        } #end of else #(l2>l1)

}  #end of function is_pair_edit1

V <- lapply(1:N,function(x){sample(1:k,5,replace=TRUE)})
DT1= data.table(ID=sample((N+1):(2*N)),V)
DT = rbindlist(list(DT,DT1))
ID_pair1 <- ID_pair
ID_pair1$V2 <- ID_pair1$V2+N #to generate IDs referencing sentences of length 5.

s_hash <- hash(DT$ID,DT$V)

print(system.time({
        y <- mapply(is_pair_edit1,ID_pair1$V1,ID_pair1$V2) }))

print(DT[ID==ID_pair1[y][1,]$V1])
print(DT[ID==ID_pair1[y][1,]$V2])
```

`is_pair_edit1` checks if the referenced sentences are one insertion away from each other. 
For example, I added 2000 random sentences (char vectors of length 5) and created another set of 100,000 ID pairs to check with this function `is_pair_edit1`

Is there a nice solution for this function as well ? i'm afraid it is NOT vectorized.

why is the performance of mapply so slow, even for simple functions like these ones ?

BTW, i'm not 100% sure of the following, but in my main code (the code here is just a simplified example), i'm running those 2 functions inside a loop (whose parameter is the LENGTH of the sentences).
i've corrected the code with Khashaa proposed solution for substitution pairs, and its super fast indeed...if i run this piece of code alone, *BUT* "strangely" because inside the same loop, i was running BOTH mapply, the total running time did NOT decrease, (it would decrease of course if in the loop i forget about the second function and put it in comment, and just run the modified code for is_pair_sub inside the loop).

Comment: This is not robust, but `adist` works good for this particular example.

Comment: Profile your code and you will see that most of the time is actually spent in your `is_pair_sub` function. If you can't use one of the available distance functions (from base R or some package, written in C), you'll have to write your own in C (e.g., using Rcpp).

Comment: Of course C is faster. But within R what improvement are possible ?

Comment: There is a reason why existent distance functions are implemented in C. You won't get sufficient performance with pure R.

Comment: @Roland in this example, i should program the function myself,as i didn't find any R package providing the right function that i need... but to get more performance, the best is ... simply NOT to use R for this kind of problems ! or so it seems !

Comment: @Kota Mori i think adist is doing something a bit different than what i need here